# Missing Element on RDFa

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool, rdfa

sorry for my english...

I have a Website and I'll eBooks to offer, I build my RDFa for a Book this,

```
<main vocab="http://schema.org/" typeof="eBook">
<h1 class="title-book">Title</h1>
<h2>Introduction to Linux </h2>
<h2>A Hands on Guide</h2>
<p><b>Author: </b> Machtelt Garrels</p> 
<span typeof="Book" resource="http://en.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/index.html">

<meta property="name" content="Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide"/>
<meta property="author" typeof="Person" content="Machtelt Garrels"/>
<span property="about" content="textbook, English">
</span>
</span>
```

When test with **search.google.com/structured-data** it to say,
[image]

I do try to give the Author name, but can't.

Can Please someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: What if you exclude `<meta property="author" typeof="Person"/>` and change the next line to `<meta property="author" content="Machtelt Garrels">`?

Comment: I am very new with **schema.org**..., I thought first should declared  **Person** and later name the person....

Comment: Try this: replace both of those lines with `<meta property="author" typeof="Person" content="Machtelt Garrels"/>`. That should cover it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This seems to work: `<span property="author" typeof="Person">
<p><strong>Author:</strong><span property="name" content="Machtelt Garrels">Machtelt Garrels</span></p> 
</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Henry Visotski, Thanks, but people help me with the solution...

```
<h2 property="name">
 <span class="title">Introduction to Linux</span>
 <span hidden="">–</span>
 <span class="subtitle">A Hands on Guide</span>
</h2>
<p property="author" typeof="Person">
<b>Author:</b>
<span property="name">Machtelt Garrels</span>
```

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it to work!